# Stop a primeng dropdown from showing if it has no sub dropups

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, primeng

I have a health care company dropdown that when selected shows a sub dropdown containing the plans
Im trying to get the the company not to show if the user has selected all the plans in it.

I also wish to auto show the plans of the company rather than selecting it first

Code: HTML

```
<div *ngIf="selectedCompany" class="div-gap"></div>
<div *ngIf="selectedCompany && cPlans && cPlans.length > 0" class="ui-g-12">
    <div>
        <p-dropdown [options]="cPlans" defaultLabel="Seleccione" [(ngModel)]="selectedPlanId">
        </p-dropdown>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code: TS

```
getHealthCareCompanies() {
    this.healthCareCompaniesService.getAll().subscribe(result => {
        this.hcCompaniesList = Util.getArraySelectItem(result, 'person.companyName');
        // this.newHcCompaniesList = this.hcCompaniesList.filter(company => company.plans.length > 0);
        console.log('HC',this.hcCompaniesList);
    }, error => {
        console.log('error')
    });
}

getPlans(){
    this.healthcarePlanService.getAll().subscribe(result => {
        this.plansCombo = Util.getArraySelectItem(result, 'description')
        console.log('Plans',this.plansCombo)
    }, error => {
        console.log('Error obteniendo planes.', error);
    });
}
```

currently im cheating by just displaying a div when there is no plans, but i would prefer no company to show at all when there is no plans

[image]

[image]

i added the ts functions

[image]

Comment: Can you add some screenshots?

Comment: added the screenshots buddy

Answer (score 0):

You should filter `hcCompaniesList` in the .ts file. Such as:

```
newHcCompaniesList = hcCompaniesList.filter(company => company.plans.length > 0);
```

-- edit

```
getHealthCareCompanies() {
    this.healthCareCompaniesService.getAll().subscribe(result => {
        this.hcCompaniesList = result.filter(company: HealthCareCompany => company.healthCarePlans);
        console.log('HC',this.hcCompaniesList);
    }, error => {
        console.log('error')
    });
}
```

Comment: i added the functions i currently use to attain the info from the server

Comment: @AidanWard Can I see the results of `console.log('HC',this.hcCompaniesList);`

Comment: just added it dude

Comment: @AidanWard How does it look now?

Comment: no luck buddy. it says cannot find name company. thanks for the help though